# multiprocessing code gets stuck

Tags: python-multiprocessing

I am using python 2.7 on windows 7 and I am currently trying to learn parallel processing.

I downloaded the multiprocessing 2.6.2.1 python package and installed it using pip.

When I try to run the foolowing very simple code, the program seems to get stuck, even after one hour it doesn't exit the execution despite the code to be super simple.

What am I missing?? thank you very much

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

array =[1,2,3,4,5]

p=Pool()
result = p.map(f, array)
p.close()
p.join()
print result
```

Comment: In python 2.7 multiprocessing library is built-in, there is no need to download it separately.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the way multiprocessing works. Think of it as python opening a new instance and importing all the modules all over again. You'll want to use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` convention. The following works fine:

```
import multiprocessing

def f(x):
    return x * x

def main():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    result = p.imap(f, xrange(1, 6))
    print list(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have changed a few other parts of the code too so you can see other ways to achieve the same thing, but ultimately you only need to stop the code executing over and over as python re-imports the code you are running.